# Html.ActionLink sometimes doesn't redirect to the expected path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I have the following button on my website

```
@Html.ActionLink("Stock Manager", "Index", "StockManager",
 new { area = "Home" }, new { @class = "logo-stock-manager", @style = "float:left;" })
```

With the following method in the **StockManagerController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

Some people that use my website have reported that when they're on **localhost/Home/Quiosk/Index** and click the button I mentioned they get redirected to **localhost** without any additional path instead of **localhost/Home/StockManager/Index**, they said that cleaning the browser data fixed it but sometimes it starts happening again.

I haven't had this problem in development or testing so I've never been able to debug it.

I release updates for my website every other week but I haven't changed these buttons in a while so I don't understand how cached data could be the problem.
Is there a better approach to what I'm currrently doing? Using something different than ActionLink maybe ?

Comment: It is possible that they are losing session and it works again after cleaning cache because the user is prompted to login again. However this is just speculation. I believe this kind of questions are not suitable for SO. According to the guidelines you need to reproduce the problem before asking for help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the '`Html.ActionLink`' in .NET MVC to create a link to another view within the same application, it will generate a URL based on the routing configuration of yout application. If the URl generated by the link redirects to '`localhost`' only, it is likely due to:

1. Incorrect Routing
2. Incorrect method parameters on '`Html.ActionLink`'
3. Bad SSL Configuration (if is the case)
4. Incorrectly specified path on route configuration

Check these 4 points, probably is one of them